# ¿Cómo funciona el método compareTo usando PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, queue

Estoy haciendo un programa donde se debe controlar a los pacientes de un hospital, y para ello se debe utilizar colas. Una de ellas debe ser la `PriorityQueue` para la consulta de cardiología, donde el orden cambia según la severidad del paciente (que es un `enum`). Por lo que en la clase paciente tengo un método `compareTo()`, donde comparo la severidad, y si dos pacientes tienen la misma severidad, se compara por el tiempo de llegada, pero no consigo el resultado que quiero.

**Salida:**

```
-------------CARDIOLOGY---------------

DNI=01846423Y, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=VITAL, entry time=90

DNI=97740105H, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=VITAL, entry time=80

DNI=01835842M, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=SEVERE, entry time=160

DNI=68276778J, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=MILD, entry time=10

DNI=49613259M, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=VITAL, entry time=40

DNI=X5774564T, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=MILD, entry time=150

DNI=39803360C, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=SEVERE, entry time=30

--------------------------------------
```

**Clase Paciente:**

```java
public class Patient implements Comparable<Object> {

    private String id;
    private Specialty specialty;
    private Severity severity;
    private int entry_time;

    public Patient(String id, Specialty specialty, Severity severity, int entry_time) {
        this.id = id;
        this.specialty = specialty;
        this.severity = severity;
        this.entry_time = entry_time;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Specialty getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public Severity getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public int getEntry_time() {
        return entry_time;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nDNI=" + id + ", specialty=" + specialty + ", severity=" + severity + ", entry time="
                + entry_time + "\n";
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Patient anotherPatient = (Patient) o;
        int r = 0;
        r = Integer.compare(anotherPatient.getSeverity().ordinal(), this.severity.ordinal());
        if (r == 0)
            r = Integer.compare(anotherPatient.getEntry_time(), this.entry_time);
        return r;
    }
}
```

**Severidad:**

```java
public enum Severity {
    MILD, SEVERE, VITAL;
}
```

**Archivo de pacientes:**

```
27545677A, TRAUMATOLOGY, MILD
68276778J, CARDIOLOGY, MILD
61343776Q, NEUROLOGY, SEVERE
39803360C, CARDIOLOGY, SEVERE
49613259M, CARDIOLOGY, VITAL
16037201Z, NEUROLOGY, MILD
23300040M, TRAUMATOLOGY, VITAL
82806522J, TRAUMATOLOGY, SEVERE
97740105H, CARDIOLOGY, VITAL
01846423Y, CARDIOLOGY, VITAL
21181660V, NEUROLOGY, MILD
22877728L, TRAUMATOLOGY, SEVERE
64638578E, NEUROLOGY, MILD
38398716D, NEUROLOGY, VITAL
62270858Z, NEUROLOGY, SEVERE
X5774564T, CARDIOLOGY, MILD
01835842M, CARDIOLOGY, SEVERE
08320899M, TRAUMATOLOGY, VITAL
Z1773688W, TRAUMATOLOGY, SEVERE
54113150S, NEUROLOGY, SEVERE
66095856C, NEUROLOGY, MILD
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `compareTo` utilizando PriorityQueue funciona como dice la
[documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements --

Entonces en la 1er posición estará el elemento menor a todos en la lista.

Ahora, en la implementación del método `compareTo` de la interfaz [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) debe devolver el elemento menor entre a y b.

---

Si en la lista de prioridad se agregan los números

```
1,5,2,8,6
```

Los elementos en la lista se ordenarán de forma natural: `1,2,5,6,8`

---

En tu PriorityQueue se agregaran objetos Patient, por lo que en el método compareTo debes devolver el menor entre a y b según el caso que corresponda.

El método ordinal() de los enumerados dice que son representados de la siguiente forma

```
MILD: 0
SEVERE: 1
VITAL: 2
```

Entonces, en el caso de la severidad.

```
if(a > b) return a
```

Al contrario de lo que parece, si la lista de prioridad ordena de menor a mayor, si "a" es mayor que "b" por lógica se debería devolver b que es menor; pero este no es el caso.

Hablamos de severidad, si "a" es mayor que "b" (mira el orden de los enum), se debe devolver "a" por ser mayor `VITAL=2`. Pero al ser mayor se ordenará después de "b", entonces para darle
prioridad devolvemos -1 que es la máxima prioridad entre "a" y "b".

```
if(a > b) return -1 // mas prioridad para "a"
else return 1 // mas prioridad para "b"
```

Tu metodo compareTo deberia ser algo así

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Patient anotherPatient = (Patient) o;
    
    if(this == anotherPatient) {
        return 0; // me comparo conmigo -> p1.compareTo(p1)
    }
    
    // una de las dos severidades es más grave.
    if(getSeverity() != anotherPatient.getSeverity()) {
        int thisSeverity = getSeverity().ordinal();
        int anotherSeverity = anotherPatient.getSeverity().ordinal();
        return (thisSeverity > anotherSeverity) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    
    // la severidad son las mismas
    // comparar quien estuvo esperando más.
    
    int thisTime = getEntry_time();
    int anotherTime = anotherPatient.getEntry_time();
    
    return (thisTime > anotherTime) ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

Operador ternario

```
(condición) ? si : no
```

Prueba

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Patient patient1 = new Patient("IDDQD", Specialty.CARDIOLOGY, Severity.MILD, 200);
    Patient patient2 = new Patient("IDKFA", Specialty.CARDIOLOGY, Severity.VITAL, 201);
    Patient patient3 = new Patient("...", Specialty.CARDIOLOGY, Severity.SEVERE, 200);
    Patient patient4 = new Patient("...", Specialty.CARDIOLOGY, Severity.SEVERE, 300);
    
    PriorityQueue<Patient> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    priorityQueue.add(patient1);
    priorityQueue.add(patient2);
    priorityQueue.add(patient3);
    priorityQueue.add(patient4);
    
    priorityQueue.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Salida:

```
DNI=IDKFA, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=VITAL, entry time=201
DNI=..., specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=SEVERE, entry time=300
DNI=..., specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=SEVERE, entry time=200
DNI=IDDQD, specialty=CARDIOLOGY, severity=MILD, entry time=200
```

Según la severidad, y si son lo mismo, según el tiempo.